# Cannot download app from family sharing (app already downloaded)

Tags: ios-appstore, family-sharing

I have recently configured Family Sharing (2 accounts are currently part of it). Most of the apps download just fine, but there are some exceptions.

**Example:** account A has Twitter in its purchased list; if account B tries to download Twitter from the store, the little cloud icon appears (and this is expected, since the app has indeed been downloaded by a family member already), but the download fails with an error message that says that the app has already been purchased by another user.

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Are these two accounts on the same machine?

Comment: @eggyal No, they are on two different iPads.

Comment: Oh, sorry.  I overlooked the [tag:ios-appstore] tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a solution, it's another iOS 8 bug. These are the steps to solve this:

> 1. Launch the App Store on your iOS device.
> 2. Select the "Featured" tab and scroll to the bottom.
> 3. Tap on your Apple ID and select "Sign Out."
> 4. Tap on "Sign In" and log in with your Apple ID.

[Source](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-fix-this-annoying-family-share-bug-in-ios-8/)